# Why \cref or \lccref does not work for assumption?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using latex with rmarkdown package. The following is the YAML heading in which the packages are located and the written text.

```
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \usepackage{bbm}
- \numberwithin{equation}{section}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{indentfirst}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{verbatim}
- \usepackage{chronosys}
- \usepackage{stackengine}
- \usepackage{booktabs, colortbl, xcolor}
- \usepackage{babel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
- \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
- \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
- \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
- \theoremstyle{definition} 
- \newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
- \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
- \newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
- \newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}
- \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
- \UseRawInputEncoding
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=black,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = blue,      
     urlcolor=blue,
     }
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{flafter}
- \floatstyle{plaintop}
- \restylefloat{table}
- \setlength{\parindent}{2.5em}
- \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes} 
- \usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
- \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
- \creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
- \creflabelformat{assumption}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
- \creflabelformat{proposition}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
- \creflabelformat{figure}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{table}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{section}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
...
```

```
\medskip
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\color{red}\@thefnmark}}}
 \newcommand{\lccref}[1]{\lcnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}}
 \makeatother 
\pagebreak
  \tableofcontents
 
\pagebreak
\section{Introduction}


\begin{assumption}\label{assump1}
    \normalfont The production is assumed to adopt a single technology.
    \end{assumption}

    \cref{assump1} suggests something.
```

But it prints `?? suggests something.`.

Comment: what happens if you add `\crefname{assumption}{assumption}{assumptions}` to this...?

Comment: @cmhughes, oh it works. Thanks! But the link's color is black and thin font. Could you let me know how to make it red and also bold font?

Comment: Please advise how or where `\lccref` is defined.

Comment: @Mico, I put it in the text as the following: `\medskip
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\color{red}\@thefnmark}}}
 \newcommand{\lccref}[1]{\lcnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}}
 \makeatother 
\pagebreak
  \tableofcontents
 
\pagebreak
\section{Introduction}`. Please see the revised question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load `amsthm` *before* `hyperref` and `cleveref`, you do not need to execute any of the `\creflabelformat` directives (as they're essentially replicating the respective defaults), and you don't need to run `\crefname{assumption}{assumption}{assumptions}` either.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{amsthm} % for \theoremstyle and \newtheoerem macros
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\theoremstyle{definition} % <-- new (to use upright font shape for theorem body)
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}


\begin{document}
\begin{assumption}\label{assump1}
Production is assumed to adopt a single technology.
\end{assumption}

\noindent
According to \cref{assump1}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: OP wants the links in bold. I guess one could add `\crefname{assumption}{\textbf{Assumption}}{\textbf{Assumptions}}\creflabelformat{assumption}{#2\textbf{#1}#3}` but there might be a better way.

Comment: @frabjous - I'd say that, from a typographical/aesthetic point of view, it's a simply hideous idea to render a cross-referencing call-out in **bold** (as well as in red). If the OP truly believes that it's a good idea to render the cross-referencing call-out in bold, he/she can always write `\textbf{\cref{assump1}}`.

Comment: I completely agree aesthetically. (Though I think the red might be worse than the bold.) It's possible the OP has a very unusual use case that throws usual good practice out the window.

Comment: @frabjous - For sure, if this were my document, I'd replace `allcolors=red` with `allcolors=blue` (or some other color that's much less obtrusive than red)...

Comment: @mico, I agree. Could you also let me know how to make only number part to be blue without making assumption to be blue?

Comment: You could remove or change the options to the hyperref package and then use something like `\creflabelformat{assumption}{#2\textcolor{blue}{#1}#3}`. (You may need to add a package like `xcolor` if hyperref isn't loading it.)

Comment: @frabjous, thanks. Also I don't like capitalized `a` but instead I want `According to assumption 1`. Could you let me know how?

Comment: @joe - If you don't want `cleveref` to capitalize the first letter in the word "assumption", don't specify the option `capitalize` when you load the package. And if you don't want `cleveref` to render the word "assumption" (or "Assumption") in a color, don't specify the option `nameinlink`.

Comment: @Mico, the code keeps crashing with `Option clash for package hyperref` errro. Could you take a look at the updated question above?

Comment: @joe - Never load a package twice. Your code loads `hyperref` twice. Don't do it. Get rid of the instruction `\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}`.

Comment: @Mico OK, but now assumption gets back to `??`. Did I remove wrong item?

Comment: @joe -- All of the `\newtheorem` directives must come after, not before, `cleveref` is loaded -- as is the case in the sample code I provided in my answer, and is noted in the second bullet point item in section 14.1 of the user guide of the `cleveref` package.

Comment: @Mico, thanks so much. Sorry I keep bothering you. Just one last question: I removed `capitalize` option, but still `Assumption` instead of `assumption` even with `\lccref`. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @joe - You've shown that `\lccref` makes use of `\lcnamecref`, but you haven't revealed how `\lcnamecref` is defined. Sadly, but probably not surprisingly, my mind reading skills have always been, and will always be, absolutely worthless. All I can surmise is that `\lcnamecref` performs the uppercasing of the first letter in "assumption".

Comment: I'm assuming `\lccref` stands for lower case ref? It's weird to have that as a custom definition. Without the capitalize option, there are two separate commands `\cref` and `\Cref`, and you would usually use the former for lowercase and the latter for the first letter uppercase (if needed at the start of a sentence). You can tweak them with `\crefname` and `\Crefname`. E.g., the original suggestion of `\crefname{assumption}{assumption}{assumptions}`. If you're still struggling, post a new complete document showing your current problem.

Comment: @Mico, could specify where I can find the definition of `lcnamecref`?

Comment: @frabjous, yes, finally everything works perfect. thanks for your comment above. Based on your comments, I just removed the `lccref` definition and now I have only to use `\cref` and `\Cref`.